how can i split the lambda line in gcl. unable to split just by reading this is the expression
local vip_table_for_racks = lambda prodspec, racks_, depl_: ({
2432 |   ret = ((((('### ' + depl_) + "\n") + "|Rack | S11 / S5 GTPC | S1u | S5 GTPC Roaming / S8 | LI | gNodeB |\n") + "|-----|---------------|-----|----------------------|----|--------|\n") + join(map(lambda rack_: (((((((((((('|' + rack_) + '|') + join(prodspec_utils.get_s5_gtpc_v4_vip_for_rack(prodspec_, rack_), ' ')) + '|') + join(prodspec_utils.get_s1u_v4_vip_for_rack(prodspec_, rack_), ' ')) + '|') + join(prodspec_utils.get_roaming_vips_for_rack(prodspec_, rack_, 'S5_GTPC_ROAMING'))) + '|') + marconi_db.service_vip_ipv4(marconidb_instance, rack, 'epc_li')) + '|') + join(prodspec_utils.get_gnodeb_ip_range_for_rack(prodspec_, rack_), ' ')) + '|'), racks_), "\n"))
can someone help me to understand the breakage
local vip_table_for_racks = lambda prodspec, racks_, depl_: ({
2432 |   ret = ((((('### ' + depl_) + "\n") + "|Rack | S11 / S5 GTPC | S1u | S5 GTPC Roaming / S8 | LI | gNodeB |\n") + "|-----|---------------|-----|----------------------|----|--------|\n") + join(map(lambda rack_: (((((((((((('|' + rack_) + '|') + join(prodspec_utils.get_s5_gtpc_v4_vip_for_rack(prodspec_, rack_), ' ')) + '|') + join(prodspec_utils.get_s1u_v4_vip_for_rack(prodspec_, rack_), ' ')) + '|') + join(prodspec_utils.get_roaming_vips_for_rack(prodspec_, rack_, 'S5_GTPC_ROAMING'))) + '|') + marconi_db.service_vip_ipv4(marconidb_instance, rack, 'epc_li')) + '|') + join(prodspec_utils.get_gnodeb_ip_range_for_rack(prodspec_, rack_), ' ')) + '|'), racks_), "\n"))

Please edit your question and Markdown it correctly
